# How to cancel event of spinner field in ExtJS 4.1?

Tags: extjs, event-handling, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am developing application using ExtJS 4.1. I have one spinner field and I want to change value of that method programatically. I have set up listeners like `change`, `spinup` and `spindown` for this same spinner field.

Now I would like to know how to prevent listener method of these events getting fired only when I change the value of spinner field through my program?

For example,

```
var mySpinner = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#foopanel > #mySpinner')[0];
mySpinner.setValue(2000);
```

When `mySpinner.setValue(2000);` line is executed, change event of `mySpinner` gets fired and as I have listener method for this change event, that listener method is executed.

Is it possible to prevent invocation of `change` event listener method?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could suspend all events by calling

```
mySpinner.suspendEvents();
mySpinner.setValue(2000);
mySpinner.resumeEvents();
```

That would be the cleanest an easiest way IMO

And that's also a usecase why this methods exist